# Convert an array of chars to an array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, char, int, type-conversion

I have these arrays

```
char[] array = {'1', '2', '3', '4'};
int[] sequence = new int[array.Length];
```

Is there an easy way to assign the numbers in `array` to `sequence`?

I tried this

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    seqence[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
}
```

But I get the ASCII coding of 1, 2, 3, 4 not the numbers by itself.

Comment: Try changing the numbers in the string from '1' to "1" and so on. This should change it so they change to integers.

Comment: `But I get the ASCII coding of 1,2,3,4 not the numbers themselves`.  Actually, you get the 32-bit signed integer of the _Unicode_ character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert the `char` to a `string` first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
     sequence[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i].ToString());
}
```

But of course, you could do this all in a single linq query:

```
char[] array = {'1', '2', '3', '4'};
int[] sequence = array.Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 11):

```
using System.Linq;

char[] array = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
var ints = array.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you convert each character to a string first, then use `int.Parse` (or still `Convert.ToInt32`) that will work.

Personally I'd use LINQ for this, e.g.

```
int[] sequence = array.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
```

... or use `ToList` if you're just as happy with `List<int>`.

If you want to use [`Char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.getnumericvalue.aspx) as suggested in another answer, you can use that with LINQ too:

```
int[] sequence = array.Select(x => (int) char.GetNumericValue(x)).ToArray();
```

Note that the cast to `int` is required because `char.GetNumericValue` returns a `double`. (There are Unicode characters for values such as "a half" for example.)

Or if you're absolutely sure you're just going to have ASCII digits, you could use the quick and dirty:

```
int[] sequence = array.Select(x => x - '0').ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
 {
     seqence[i] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(array[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can may be use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) to achieve that. It generates a sequence of consecutive numbers from - to.

Just an example:

```
 IEnumerable<int> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
```

This is in the case if original char array is just a consecutive sequence of numbers in char.

If array is subject of arbitrary order and sequence, just use correct convertion:

```
array.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate over your char array and use the next conversion:

```
char[] charArray = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };

int[] intArray= new int[charArray .Length];

for (int i = 0; i < charArray .Length; i++)
{
    intArray[i] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(charArray[i]);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    sequence[i] = array[i] - '0';
}
```

There are many correct answers here, but (unless you want to use unsafe code) this is the fastest, and it doesn't use additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char[] array = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };

int[] sequence = new int[array.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    sequence[i] = int.Parse(array[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your Char value to String before converting to Integer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
  sequence[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i].ToString());
}
```